# Windows 10 mind blowing slow boot times due to idle (94.32% of the time according to WPA)

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

I have had this PC I'm writing from for like three years now and at first things appeared to be just fine about boot times, but I remember that soon after (maybe one year after I built it) it started having insanely mind blowing boot times (around 8 minutes from when I press the power button to when I can fully use it) and this is even stranger cause I have a pretty decent PC, I'm running the following specs:

1. **Motherboard**: MSI Z270 Gaming Pro Carbon
2. **CPU**: Intel i7 7700k Kaby Lake 4.2GHz (currently overclocked and running at 4.8 GHz)
3. **GPU**: MSI GTX 1060 6GB
4. **RAM**: Crucial Ballistix 3600 MHz CL16 (16GB)

So today i decided to finally address the problem and googled around a little bit; I found this Windows Performance Recorder and Analyzer tool from Microsoft and decided to try it out. I even planned on compressing the .etl file and upload it so it could've been helpful in case but at the end of the day it turned out to be 7GB of data and it would took me probably a full week just to upload it (0.5 Mbps upload speed shared with all the family) so I'll just attach a screenshot I took.

[image]

What could be causing this insanely mind blowing idle times during the boot and how could I fix this?

**EDIT:** I tried removing all the hard drives except the one where my system is installed and it didn't solve my problem, the boot time went down just to 408 seconds which is almost 7 minutes. I did the boot trace again and that's what I get

[image]

Comment: What's been going on with disk #3? It seems to be active pretty much continuously.

Comment: @StarCat: The actual problem is that the WPA doesn't say which disk is "disk 3" and I have no idea of how to check which is it (like, the label it has in Windows)

Comment: Pull the SATA cables on all but the boot drive. Process of elimination. Or use Speccy to get the drive serial number, then reference the label on the top of the drive.

Comment: @spikey_richie: Apparently that disk 3 is the disk where I have the system. I added another screenshot in the body of the question in case it could be useful. PS: The idle time just increased even more ahahah

Comment: There's one thing (at least) you forgot to tell us: your system disk, is it a regular hard drive or an SSD? If the latter, is the firmware up-to-date? Is Windows fully up-to-date too? You have 16GB of RAM, but how many sticks? When you go into your BIOS/UEFI, is it all accounted for, and at the proper clock speed? What are your SATA settings like? AHCI enabled? There are many unknowns here, but decent specs don't necessarily mean decent performance, especially with Windows 10. Did you enable Fast Startup? If so, disable it and run a trace again, to see if there's an improvement or not.

Comment: @Dider: I'm gonna add the informations I'm sure about: 16GB RAM is 2x8GB, my Windows is on an HDD, for the BIOS I just manually changed some of the CL related parameters and voltage for the RAM but the problem showed up way before I switched to those (basically they are one month old), everything else was changed via presets so I assume they're correct. Fast boot is disabled. Not sure about the SATA settings, if it may help it's untouched so the default ones.

Comment: The file you recorded probably compresses very well. Have you tried using 7-Zip?

Comment: @DanielB: Unfortunately I have low HDD space (around 40ish GB on my system hard drive) so I had to get rid of it. I might get another boot trace and try to compress that but even something around 1GB would be too much on a 0.5Mbps ADSL...

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Disable hibernation : `powercfg -h off`. (2) Use the free [BootRacer](https://www.greatis.com/bootracer/index.html) to analyze the boot. (3) Disconnect all possible devices and try to boot. (4) Run chkdsk. (5) Verify the disk SMART info (for example using [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)). (6) Post an ETL file.

Comment: Have a look at the Life Time by Process view of the trace - here is an example I've found: https://imgur.com/a/1v2NrBF Look at the Start Time column. Anything look odd?

Comment: You seem to have abandoned your bounty.

Comment: It's difficult to say from the info you've given, but I'm questioning the fitness of the HDD.  If you have access to a copy of SpinRite, I'd give that a shot to see if it finds any problem areas on the disk.  You'll see the remaining time fluctuate significantly if it has trouble reading certain sectors.  The interface is very 1993, but don't let that scare you.  Otherwise, I'd pop in a live Linux USB stick and try to copy from the 'root' disk device (/dev/sda, not /dev/sda1) to /dev/null and measure the throughput from the disk with iotop, dstat or something similar.